# In one project i seen serialize method outside model in models.py file

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

what is use of def serialize? Why outside of model method serialize present?. why on user once again serialize is used

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    """
    This model stores the doctor profile.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    create_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Whether this doctor is accessible to users.
    qualification = models.TextField(null=True)
    specialization = models.ManyToManyField(DoctorSpecialization)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.user.serialize(),
            "created_on": generate_readable_date_time(self.create_on),
            "active": self.active,
            "qualification": self.qualification,
            "specializations": [s.serialize() for s in self.specialization.all()]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the simplest way of serializing your data. Mostly used for small data, cannot handle complex objects with complex attributes well. If you do not want to use Django or DRF serializers, you can easily use this method.

Comment: I have known Django or DRF serializer but in internship they are using like this is this professional approach they are using.

Comment: @JAYESHrathi I am not certain that this usage should be called unprofessional but I can say that they are not paying attention to lots of benefits that framework serializers bring to the table.